# Boolean Algebra: Simplifying product of sums

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to simplify

```
 (A+B+C)(A+notB+C)(notA+B+notC)
```

The K-map gives me

```
(A+C)(notA+B+notC)
```

but when I use boolean algebra I get

```
(A+AC+C)(notA+B+notC)
```

Can someone explain to me how to simplify this using algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that:
$$
A + AC + C = (A + AC) + C = A(1 + C) + C = A(1) + C = A + C
$$

Comment: Can you explain how A(1+C)+C=A(1)+C?

Comment: For any propositional variable $X$, we have that $1 + X = 1$. This is known as Domination Law. A true statement that is ORed together with any other statement must always be true.

Comment: I see, thanks. I better brush up on logical equivalences

Answer (score 0):

We'll focus on the first two factors. By the distributive law, we have $$(\color{red}{A}+\color{blue}B+\color{red}{C})(\color {red} A+\color{blue}{\lnot B} + \color{red}C) = [\color{red}{(A+C)}+\underbrace{(\color{blue}{B\cdot\lnot B)}}_{\large = 0}] = (A+C)$$

The second factor remains unchanged, to get $$(A+C)(\lnot A + B + \lnot C)$$